# Multiple and different conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multiple-conditions

I have a problem with logic.
If the number is **higher than 0** and **less than 10** AND the **number is 11** AND the **number is 22** do something. (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 or 22).

And ELSE IF the number is **higher than 10** BUT is **NOT 11** or is **NOT 22**, do something else. (10, 12, 13 ....20, 21, 23, 24...)

I got to do only with 11, but I have no clue how to insert another condition with 22.

```
if (n >= 0 && n < 10) || (n == 11 && n == 22) {
        do something

    } else if (n >= 10 && n != 11) && (n != 22) {
        do something else
    }
```

Comment: "the number is 11 AND the number is 22"? Can you explain? I don't understand how a number can have two values.

Comment: @Leau if the number is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 11 or 22, do something. And the second condition (else if) is equal or higher than 10, but don't include the numbers 11 or 22.

Comment: Change the first it statement to use `||` when checking if n is 11 OR 22.

Comment: Why does your code use `n >= 0`, when you want it to start at `1`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I learned this way. Is not necessary since I can't have 0?

Comment: @Terry it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(n >= 1 && n <= 9) || n == 11 || n == 22` which will check if the number is between 1 and 9 inclusive (1 to 9) ***OR*** it's 11 ***OR*** it's 22.

Then, in your else if, just check for >= 10 - numbers less than 1 e.g. 0, won't trigger the else either.

```
if ((n >=1 0 && n <= 9) || n == 11 || n == 22) {
    do something
} else if (n >= 10) {
    do something else
}
```

Use >= and <= to make it clearer what values you're looking for otherwise it takes a little extra mental load to realise that `n > 0 && n < 10` really means values 1 to 9.

Also, it's JavaScript and numbers can either be integral or floating point, so greater than zero could be 0.1 etc.

Comment: It worked! I'm still learning how the logic works. "really means values 1 to 9" this makes totally sense for me now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example of (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 or 22) it sounds like this is what you're going for?

```
if ((n > 0 && n < 10) || n == 11 || n == 22) {
  // do something
} else if (n >= 10) {
  // do something else
}
```

Edit: Added `else if (n >= 10)` that I overlooked

Comment: "and ELSE IF the number is higher than 10", 0 shouldn't return something else, no?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I missed that part

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement, you say:

n is larger or equal to 0 AND n is smaller than 10
OR
n is equal to 11 AND n is equal to 22

Which means, the if block will run for numbers that are between 0 and 9 (inclusive) OR for the numbers 11 AND 22. So the number can either be between 0 and 9 or it can be BOTH 11 and 22, which is impossible.

My take on the if statement:

```
if (n >= 1 && n <= 9 || n == 11 || n == 22) {
    do something;
}
```

That way, you don't get confused with the inclusive and exclusive numbering and make sure that either 11 or 22 is allowed.

The second block will run for numbers that are greater or equal to 10 AND not 11 AND not 22. Which is just fine.

```
else if (n >= 10 && n != 11 && n != 22) {
    do something else;
}
```

In this answer, I assume you don't want to entirely skip the 10. If you do, then in the second statement, you would check for `n > 10`.

Logically, this is sound. However, I don't think that you need to check for 11 and 22 in the second one, as the if block will run first and if the number is 11 or 22, the first if block will run. So the second one doesn't need to account for them.

Comment: In fact, the first block worked and the second worked but was unnecessary. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition will never succeed because you can't have a number higher than 0 and less than 10 AND this same number is equal to 11 AND also being equal to 22 (in both case, it'll be more than 10).

```
if ((n > 0 && n < 10) || n == 11 || n == 22) {
    // my number is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 or 22
} else {
    // my number is almost everything except the values from above
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not what she/he asked for

Comment: I edited my topic to explain better, if it helps :)

Comment: I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||'"

Comment: can you retry please ?

Comment: I tried again and it worked! I included "else if (n >= 10) { " for the second block. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation, don't confuse [logicial AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) (`&&`) and [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) (`||`).

```js
function check(n) {
  if((n >= 1 && n <= 9) || (n == 11 || n == 22)) {
    console.log(n, true);
  } else if(n >= 10) {
    console.log(n, false);
  }
}

check(1)  // true
check(11) // true
check(22) // true
check(0)
check(10) // false
check(12) // false
check(21) // false
check(23) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the comparison and because of the [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) of [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) over [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), you need no parenthesis.

```
if (n >= 0 && n < 10 || n === 11 || n === 22) {
    // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 or 22
    // do something
} else {
    // 10, 12, 13 ... 21, 23 ...
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

To test for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 or 22:

```
if (n >= 0 && n < 10) || (n == 11 && n == 22) {
```

Can minimally be changed to:

```
if ((n > 0 && n < 10) || (n == 11 || n == 22)) {
```

The three important changes are:

- balance parentheses to make a proper `if( )` construct.
- `>= 0` becomes `> 0` to achieve the *higher than zero* requirement.
- The last `&&` becomes `||`.

This also changes the order of operations such that we don't actually need any extra parentheses at all in this case. This also happens to be correct, and is simpler:

```
if (n > 0 && n < 10 || n == 11 || n == 22) {
```

...because `&&` has higher precedence than `||` and the comparators (`>`, `<` and `==`) have higher precedence than the conditionals (`&&` and `||`).

At this point you don't need an `else if` condition.  Just `else` will suffice.  `11` and `22` are handled by the affirmative case of the `if` and therefore `n` will be neither of those things in the `else` case.

Final product:

```
if (n > 0 && n < 10 || n == 11 || n == 22) {
  // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 or 22
} else {
  // Something else.  :)
}
```

Comment: It worked too! Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Worth pointing out that this will also hit the affirmative case for a few other values of n, such as when n is `1.5`, or  `3.14`, the string `"5"`, and even if `n` has the boolean value `true` this will cause that  _if_ condition to execute the affirmative case.  JavaScript is weird, I know.

Comment: In this case it's only integer values, but anyway it's good to understand how it works.